# Padding not being understood in the UpSampling2D layer of a sequential layer

Tags: keras, keras-2

I am building a CNN model with the sequential keras API but getting the following error on line 12 `(model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2), padding='same')))`

```
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'padding')
```

I am using Keras 2.2.4 and Tensorflow 1.12.0

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

My code is:

```
# Fit regression DNN model 
print("Creating/Training CNN")
model = Sequential()
model.add( Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=(128,128,1), activation='relu', padding = 'same') )
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add( Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') )
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add( Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') )
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same', name = 'grab_that'))

model.add( Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') )
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add( Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') )
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add( Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') )
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add( Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same') )
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[binary_accuracy])
history = model.fit(data_train,data_train,verbose=1,epochs=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `UpSampling2D` layer doesn't have such parameter. Only convolutional layers have it (see [docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/)).